# Finding non-binary tree depth

Tags: c#

Can I find non-binary tree depth.
Every node can have multiple children. We don't know how much is the maximum count of nodes.

```
public class Node
{
    private List<Node> nodes;
    private string nodeName;

    public Node(string nodeName)
    {
        nodes = new List<Node>();
        this.nodeName = nodeName;
    }

    public List<Node> Nodes
    {
        get { return this.nodes; }
        set { this.nodes = value; }
    }

    protected string NodeName
    {
        get { return this.nodeName; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would it be different from a binary tree?

Comment: Do you want to find the number of nodes or the depth? These are two different things.

Comment: Do you know how to find the depth of a binary tree?  Have you done any research on how to find the depth of a non-binary tree?  What did you find, and how did it fail to answer your question?

Comment: Think this should be tagged as homework.

Comment: @DarrenYoung There is no homework tag, and for good reason.

Comment: @Servy Did I imagine it or has it been removed?

Comment: @DarrenYoung It hasn't existed since before you joined the site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this to calculate the maximum depth (*including* the root node):

```
public static int Depth(Node root, int depth)
{
    int result = depth + 1;

    foreach (var node in root.Nodes)
        result = Math.Max(result, Depth(node, depth + 1));

    return result;
}
```

You would call it passing in 0 for the initial depth:

```
int depth = Depth(root, 0);
```

If you just want to count ALL the nodes rather than the depth:

```
public static int CountExcludingRoot(Node root)
{
    return root.Nodes.Sum(node => 1 + CountExcludingRoot(node));
}
```

(This *excludes* the root node, so you need to add one to the value returned to get the total of all nodes including the root).

Comment: Thank you for your reply